# Getting iframe data from Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, jsoup

I have a web page that contain an iframe:

```
<div id="confIMG" style="display:block;">
   <iframe id="ifrmy" src="http://www.example.com" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;overflow:hidden;height:200px;width:90%;'" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
   #document
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>....</head>
      <body>....</body>
   </html>
</div>
```

for getting all of html source, i used this javascript:

```
javascript:HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

But, when the listener is invoked, i just see:

```
<div id="confIMG" style="display:block;">
   <iframe id="ifrmy" src="http://www.example.com" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;overflow:hidden;height:200px;width:90%;'" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

the issue is that all iframe document is missed. How can i get them all?

I also tried to get the page using JSOUP. in that case, i'm only get:

```
<div id="confIMG" style="display:block;"></div>
```

PS: i tried to check using Chrome browser. I can only see source code when i use `developer options / developers tools` into tab `elements`.

Answer (score 1):

JSoup won't fetch automatically the iframe content if you don't ask it to do so.

When you have first loaded the page, find the iframe then fetch it with Jsoup.

```
Document doc=...
Element ifrmy = doc.select("#ifrmy").first();

if (ifrmy!=null) {
   Document iframeContent = Jsoup.connect(ifrmy.attr("src")).get();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the only way i've found to get the iframe (and not the content but just TAG) is using javascript...when i try to get the page using JSOUP, i got just the empty DIV! Seems that JSOUP is getting just first DIVs levels

Comment: @fabrysious can you please add an answer how did you do it?